# Vue Draggable not working with filterBy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, vue.js, vue-component

I am using vue draggable component to drag and drop objects from one div to another. I am also using filterBy filtering the `v-model`. The problem is when I filter(and for example get 1 result) and try to drag and drop the item the very first from all items is dropped and not the dragged item.

Dragging from:

```
<draggable :list="available" class="draggable" :options=" group:'stuff'}">
   <div v-for="people in filterBy(available, filter_available, 'name')" class="list-item">
      <img :src="image" height="20"> {{ name }}
   </div>
</draggable>
```

Dropping to:

```
<draggable :list="drop" class="draggable" :options="{group:'stuff'}">
    <div v-for="people in filterBy(drop, filter_doppred, 'name')" class="list-item">
       <img :src=image" height="20"> {{ name }}
    </div>
</draggable>
```

On it's own both features are working fine. However, when filtering the results, it changes the index of the elements and when moving from one list to another - I move a different item, not the one dragged.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to pass the same list to the draggable component that you use for the v-for - both need the filtered result.

You currently use a method to do the filter operation. You would have t call this method twice to get the same result to both places.

You should instead use a computed property to avoid doing the same operation twice.

Edit: the draggable component will mutate the provided list, which will not affect your source data when you use a computed property.

After looking at the docs for vue-draggable, you should probably use the `change`event provided by the component (https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events) to update your source data.

I can't give you a concrete example because I don't know what your logic is to determine the new position of the moved element in the unfiltered source list.

Comment: When I pass the same list to the draggable component It stops working..

Answer (score 1):

Mostly I agree with @LinusBorg, with some minor differences:

1) draggable list props and v-for must use a collection

2) Create a different array for the filtered array. A computed property won´t work as draggable will try to change it. You can use a data field and use watch if the master array may change.

3) Listen the change event to propagate change on the master array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's happening because SortableJS uses indexes to get the currently dragged element.

```
// Sortable.js:341
// Get the index of the dragged element within its parent
startIndex = _index(target, options.draggable);
```

I have a similar case:
several sets of drag'n'drop groups should share the same list of items, and the items cannot repeat across sets.

I think I'll end up with adding/removing the elements manually.

Comment: Hence it's not going to work on one master list with multiple "views" between which you drag and drop. That matches my experience.

The events use "indexes" into the *same* array, but the code "thinks" they're different arrays. 
   => They assume multiple separate lits.

I see no solution here other than splitting the master array into separate arrays. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I added a property(visible) to my object, when the filter change I set the property to true if is still visible, to false if not. Based on the property i hide or show the element to avoid create a new array with filterBy, filterBy is the reason the index changes and does not match with the original array (cause it creates a new one).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: He is trying to filters results from a list to allow the user search something specific and is using filterBy, but filterBy creates a new array as results when he drag an elements it drags another because the vuedraggable is based on the index, as a workaround he is able to add a property to each element of the list and use that property to toggle the visibility of the element i do not know why my answer is unclear